# How do you ruse Index Match functions in appsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I created a rate chart for the prices of services and items provided.

generic chart:

[image: rate chart example]

In Sheets, I'm able to run an index and match function (see below) to fetch the corresponding price for each service (column) and item (row), however in appsheet, I'm not sure where to even put this:

```
INDEX(ratechart!$C$2:$K$14,MATCH($F2,ratechart!$A$2:$A$14,0),MATCH($Y2,ratechart!$C$1:$K$1,0))
```

appsheet doesn't seem to accept index() as a function or I'm doing it wrong (this fn does work in sheets).  My spreadsheet will list thousands of rows and already has a number of formulas, so I'd really like appsheet to tackle this so my app and spreadsheet aren't slow.

[image]

(the results would display in Column F)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Please do not add your spreadsheet as an image.